# Express-validation vs required attribute

Tags: node.js, ejs, required, express-validator

I am making a ***nodejs login app*** using EJS framework. From the tutorials I have watched, I see them using ***express-validation to prevent submission while some input fields are empty***. I tried the same using the ***required attribute*** for the input field and it just worked fine and was easier. Should I use express-validation or required attribute and what are the advantages of one over the other?

Answer (score 1):

Express.js is a framework, sitting on top of Node.js, an event driven non-blocking JavaScript runtime, that sits on top of the V8 engine.

Node.js and Express is **server side** JavaScript.

HTML5 is **client side**.

Adding a 'required' attribute to a HTML5 **client side** DOM element enforces the users particular browser to display a message to the user when they invoke a submit event on the html5 form element (client side, before any data payload has been HTTP POSTed to the server side code)... in your case a Node.js Express.js app.

To answer your question:

1. explore and understand the difference between **client side** and **server side** code.
2. use HTML5 required attribute on a form element if you want the browser to tell the user they must enter a value in that form input.
3. use the npm 'Express-validation' middleware to perform **server side** 'formatting' / 'sanitization' on the user input values to attempt prevention of web app security vulnerabilities e.g. NoSQL injection / persistent XSS / reflected XSS / DOM XSS type attacks.